# python running task in the background while allowing tkinter to be active

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

When my program executes the python GUI freezes.  Here is my main code.  Can I get some help in doing threading? So the execution happens in the background and I can still be able to use the "x" button in the GUI if I want to end the execution?  Currently I just ask the user to close the cmd to end the program.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk() 
    root.title('Log')
    root.geometry("400x220") 
    font1=('times', 15)
    font2=('times', 10)
    #Label inside root 
    Label(root, relief=GROOVE, font=font2, text="level").pack() 
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set("INFO") # default value

    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, "CRITICAL", "DEBUG")
    w.pack()
    Button(root, font=font1, background= "yellow", text='START',command=main).pack()
    Label(root, text="To end just close the CMD window").pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly is suppose to be done in the thread? Are you planning on updating the GUI? Just a note, Tkinter is not thread safe.

Comment: Where is `main` function ?  Where is code with problem ? Maybe you could do this with `tk.After()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Turns out the Button callback was autorunning `launch` because the function object wasn't being set as the callback, the called function itself was. The fix is to replace the callback `lambda: spawnthread(fcn)` so that a function object is set as the callback instead. The answer has been updated to reflect this. Sorry for missing that.

---

The GUI mainloop will freeze when you try to run some other function, and has no way to restart itself (because it's frozen.)

Let's say the command you'd like to run alongside the GUI mainloop is `myfunction`.

Imports:

```
import time
import threading
import Queue
```

You need to set up a `ThreadedClient` class:

```
class ThreadedClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, fcn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.fcn = fcn
    def run(self)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(self.fcn())

def spawnthread(fcn):
    thread = ThreadedClient(queue, fcn)
    thread.start()
    periodiccall(thread)

def periodiccall(thread):
    if(thread.is_alive()):
        root.After(100, lambda: periodiccall(thread))
```

You then want the widget calling the function to instead call a `spawnthread` function:

```
queue = Queue.Queue()

Button(root, text='START',command=lambda: spawnthread(myfunction)).pack() #<---- HERE
```

N.B. I'm adapting this from a multithreaded tkinter GUI I have; I have all my frames wrapped up in classes so this might have some bugs since I've had to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I keep getting error line 26, in spawnthr
ead
    periodiccall(thread)
  File X, line 30, in periodic
call
    after(100, lambda: periodiccall(thread))
NameError: global name 'after' is not defined

Comment: Ah. Try using root.after(...) instead.

Comment: @user2980048 or even root.After(...). I haven't used tkinter in awhile, I'm not sure which one is best.

Comment: thanks that is working now after using root.After(..).  However, why is my main() function executing without me even clicking the start button?

Comment: Did it run without clicking the start button before?

Comment: Yes it ran without clicking the start button.  And when I click the close button in the ticker it didn't stop the background process that was started.

Comment: Consider renaming main() and seeing what happens.

Comment: same thing...called it Button(root, font=font1, background= "yellow", text='START',command=spawnthread(launch)).pack()

Comment: Hm. So main/launch/whatever ran automatically even before you added the threading before?

Comment: no, it only started doing this when I added spawnthread.  If i remove that from the line above it works fine.  Meaning it starts the process after clicking the start button.

Comment: So running the program without multithreading doesn't autostart it. Okay. Try moving the `queue = Queue.Queue()` line to right after the Button line (ideally right before the `def spawnthread` line)

Comment: are you placing the queue in the if __name__ == "__main__":? And wouldn't it not complain about no defining spawnthread if you put it after button line?

Comment: with queue before the spawnthread method it still behaves the same.

Comment: Try it out. I'm not in at a place where I can test right now. I see what you mean though. The function defs and class declarations should be outside of the name == 'main'. The queue line should be within.

Comment: Okay, edited again. In its current incarnation it is still auto-starting?

Comment: that is how i had it originally.  So, yes, it does auto-start.

Comment: Did some testing on my computer and I got it. What was happening was that the button callback was autorunning the function passed into it. It has to be a lambda function instead. Check the updated answer (the change is in the button line.) I also removed the font and background to make it easier to see the change.

Comment: thanks a lot. Basically using lambda allowed us to pass function to another function

Comment: one last question hopefully.  Now that the GUI is not freezing I thought about adding a stop button under the start button, which will kill the processes that started with start button.  I just put in a stop button and then did the command = stop.  In which, I just did sys.exit().  I guess that is the wrong way to exit.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try playing around with `thread.stop()` in the `periodiccall` function.