# tkinter freezing when press button with libraries like tiktoklive

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, freeze, tiktok

I face an issue and I want to understand why this problem happens and how to solve this problem. I know a lot of questions on stack overflow that talk about tkinter freeze when button pressed I saw many solutions but it is not working for me and I want some help to understand how to solve this problem, I work on some app using tkinter I trying use libraries like TikTokLive to learn new something and I tried to make a button that when pressed gives some information I tried **threading** but not working and tried to see about use queue and I understand the **queue** and I saw solutions like use **multiprocess** but nothing works for me so I thought that problem happens because of the tiktoklive library may be because we use **async** programming so I made some search and saw solution but not working, **I want to some help to understand more how to solve this problem.**

**Sample code below:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

get_information = Button(text="get", font='normal 30 bold', command=lambda: connect_with_tiktok_live())
get_information.pack()

def connect_with_tiktok_live():
    # dependencies
    import TikTokLive.types.events
    from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient
    from TikTokLive.types.events import ConnectEvent
    username = "put the username of tiktok live"

    # Instantiate the client with the user's username
    client: TikTokLiveClient = TikTokLiveClient(
        unique_id=username, **({
            "process_initial_data": False, 
            "enable_extended_gift_info": True,
        }))

    @client.on('connect')
    async def on_connect(_: ConnectEvent):
        print("Connected to Room ID: ", client.room_id)

    # Run the client and block the main thread
    # await client.start() to run non-blocking
    try:
        return client.run()
    except FailedConnection:  # if live is ended
        print('finished')
  
mainloop()
```

**gif problrm:**

[image]

**some links solution not working for me**

[How can I prevent a tkinter Gui from freezing while an async task is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71648197/how-can-i-prevent-a-tkinter-gui-from-freezing-while-an-async-task-is-running)

[python running task in the background while allowing tkinter to be active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514006/python-running-task-in-the-background-while-allowing-tkinter-to-be-active)

[Tkinter window says (not responding) but code is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522171/tkinter-window-says-not-responding-but-code-is-running/68897016#68897016)

[How to easily avoid Tkinter freezing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing)

[How to run a function in the background of tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048082/how-to-run-a-function-in-the-background-of-tkinter)

[Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multithreading here using [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) method.

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

get_information = Button(text="get", font='normal 30 bold', command= lambda:Thread(target=connect_with_tiktok_live).start())
get_information.pack()


def connect_with_tiktok_live():
    # dependencies
    import TikTokLive.types.events
    from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient
    from TikTokLive.types.events import ConnectEvent
    username = "put the username of tiktok live"

    # Instantiate the client with the user's username
    client: TikTokLiveClient = TikTokLiveClient(
        unique_id=username, **({
            "process_initial_data": False, 
            "enable_extended_gift_info": True,
        }))

    @client.on('connect')
    async def on_connect(_: ConnectEvent):
        print("Connected to Room ID: ", client.room_id)

    # Run the client and block the main thread
    # await client.start() to run non-blocking
    try:
        return client.run()
    except FailedConnection:  # if live is ended
        print('finished')
  
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this does not solve the problem if you tried putting the user name and then running to see the output when connecting with the room id. The freezing does not stop

Comment: @MohammadAlJadallah Can you provide a username? so  I can try it.

Comment: this username is live on TikTok now: ahmdarzounii
and target here you should give the function parenthesis target=connect_with_tiktok_live(). and import these >> from TikTokLive.types.errors import LiveNotFound, FailedConnection

Comment: and even if the user not opens the live now you will see the freeze: this username not open live now: developerx2

Comment: @MohammadAlJadallah okk Wait I will check/