# No solution for freezing tkinter when press button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, response, freeze

I face an issue and I want to understand why this problem happens and how to solve this problem. I know a lot of questions on stack overflow that talk about tkinter freeze when button pressed I saw many solutions but it is not working for me and I want some help to understand how to solve this problem, I work on some app using tkinter I trying use libraries like TikTokLive to learn new something and I tried to make a button that when pressed gives some information I tried **threading** but not working and tried to see about use queue and I understand the queue and I saw solutions like use **multiprocess** but nothing works for me so I thought that problem happens because of the tiktoklive library may be because we use async programming so I made some search and saw solution but not working, **I want to some help to understand more how to solve this problem.**

**Sample code below:**

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

get_information = Button(text="get", font='normal 30 bold',
                         command=lambda: Thread(target=connect_with_tiktok_live()).start)
get_information.pack()


def connect_with_tiktok_live():
     # dependencies
    import TikTokLive.types.events
    from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient
    from TikTokLive.types.events import ConnectEvent
    # from TikTokLive.types.events import
    username = "put the username of tiktok live"
 
    # Instantiate the client with the user's username
    client: TikTokLiveClient = TikTokLiveClient(
    unique_id=username, **({
            "process_initial_data": False,
            "enable_extended_gift_info": True,
        }))

    @client.on('connect')
    async def on_connect(_: ConnectEvent):
          print("Connected to Room ID: ", client.room_id)

    # Run the client and block the main thread
    # await client.start() to run non-blocking
    try:
        return client.run()
    except :  # if live is ended
        print('finished')

mainloop()
```

**some links solution not working for me**

[How can I prevent a tkinter Gui from freezing while an async task is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71648197/how-can-i-prevent-a-tkinter-gui-from-freezing-while-an-async-task-is-running)

[python running task in the background while allowing tkinter to be active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514006/python-running-task-in-the-background-while-allowing-tkinter-to-be-active)

[Tkinter window says (not responding) but code is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522171/tkinter-window-says-not-responding-but-code-is-running/68897016#68897016)

[How to easily avoid Tkinter freezing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422139/how-to-easily-avoid-tkinter-freezing)

[How to run a function in the background of tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048082/how-to-run-a-function-in-the-background-of-tkinter)

[Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)